# how to assign different templates to different page or article?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, template-override

In joomla 3, i need to know how to assign different templates to different pages or articles?

Answer (score 1):

**For Pages:**

- Inside each menu item you can see an option called **Template Style**, assign here the template for each menu item, see the screenshot:

[image]

Also you can do this if you go to:
**Extensions** > **Templates** > **Your Template** > Tab **Menu Assignment**

**For Articles:**

- You can use an **Alternative Layout** for each Article, find this option in the tab called **Options**
   at the bottom of the page, see the screenshot:

[image]

Here you can find more information:
https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

Answer (score 0):

From admin panel you can only assign template to menu item (Itemid) so you can link articles to menu items and you're good to go.

In php you can assign it via setting `templateStyle` variable.

If you want to do this without coding, to do it all through admin panel you'll need custom plugin.